# JS code working on localhost but not on production

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this Vue component showing images according to the data property item.stars.

It works fine on localhost but doesn't work on my production server. The first image is displayed, and I can see the Vue properties that should cause the other two images to be displayed, but for some reason these aren't shown.

Is there anything wrong with the JS code? How is it possible that this code works on localhost?

Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<img v-lazy="'/uploads/' + item.images[0].image_path + '_small.jpg'" :alt="item.name" style='height: auto'>

<img src='/icons/unique2.png' v-if="(item.stars.filter(e => e.star_type === 2).length > 0)" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 30%;">

<img src='/icons/Star-01.png' v-if="(item.stars.filter(e => e.star_type === 1).length > 0)" style="position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; width: 20%;">
```

Comment: Please provider a reproducible example

Comment: Check the image path properly. I think issue is on path.

Comment: Thanks @ripa for the suggestion but I confirm that the paths are correct. If they weren't, I would see a 404, whereas in my case I don't see anything. As if Vue didn't trigger the two images to be shown...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I eventually identified the issue: when replacing

> img v-if="(item.stars.filter(e => e.star_type === 2).length > 0)"

with

> img v-if="(item.stars.filter(e => e.star_type == 2).length > 0)"

the code works on my server.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your issue, please visit your production link website through Chrome browser, when it opens click on F12 / or right click on page and select inspect to open chrome console. In your case most probably the console will display errors within JavaScript code, if you resolved these errors that appear, the site will work through the production mode beside that please make sure you covered  / avoided the below points.

Points of why this problem could happen:

1. you are browsing your production site through http proxy internet or via internal gate ways which is blocking some port used in your site
2. there is error in your javascript (could be path to page content / images)
3. you are using outdated browser
4. timeout issue which is related to your server internet connection or even your client side internet connection
5. you have not set proper access permission to your folder path used on your site
6. you have not published all supported files to be viewed from your server
7. licenses of used files  could also show this issue
8. your are browsering your website through VPN connection so please disable it and try again .
9. issue on files extension/types which been used in your site content
10. duplicating the load of used javascript library on your website (most probably this your problem although I cannot see it on the provided information for your question)
11. conflict with used JavaScript library / versions on your websites

Hope this will resolve the issue for you .

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your help, but none of the points mentioned are causing the issue here.

Comment: please post a link of your production there so we can help you directly .
did you find any errors when you opened the developer tools ?